# WebScraping with BeautifulSoup JSON file in DIVs. How to pull it easily

Tags: html, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was trying to pull information from a website in a common way, using class names of required elements.

After a while, I noticed that at the top of the HTML code there is a part that looks like a JSON file with all the required information.

Here is how it looks:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1utP_ldRWCaabLKcOvsWu_6NHP3ClrdQQ

I tried to clean this file, but I still can't read it as JSON. I thought maybe it's a common issue, and someone can help me to find an easy way to pull information from this part of the HTML. It would be much faster and easier than scraping partial pieces from many places.

If anyone knows what to read I would also appreciate it.
Any help is highly valuable.

Comment: Many websites have an API which you can use instead of scraping pages. It is better to use the API because it uses less bandwidth for them, and it is less work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your data is coming using `bs4` parser so you can load the data within `JSON` using the following:

```py
import json

target = soup.find("div",class_="search-results").get("data-context")

loader = json.loads(target)

print(loader)

pretty = json.dumps(loader,indent=4)

# print(pretty) # for human readable vision.
```